# How can I assign a unique ID for each div in my javascript code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

For the following code:

```
function cdiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
    cdiv();
  }
}
```

the goal is to assign a unique `ID` for each of the divs being created. Overtime, I would like to be able to click and update a div and my thinking is a unique `ID` would help identify it in updating quickly.

Comment: you can assign id value like $(".div").attr("id","auto_value"); value you can get from for loop.

Comment: You don't need IDs for the purpose you have in mind. If you do something in response to a click then the associated event handler will have direct access to to the clicked item via [`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

Comment: @ThanhLD The question is not tagged jQuery, thus pure JavaScript answers should be given.

Comment: Something I'll have a look at, but Pranav's answer does the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a counter variable and set id based on that

```js
var id = 0; // variable for generating unique id

function cdiv() {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = 'div' + id;
  div.id = 'div' + id++; // generate unique id and then increment value
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
    cdiv();
  }
}
```

---

Another way is using both for loop variables

```js
function cdiv(str) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = 'div' + str;
  div.id = 'div' + str; // generate unique id 
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < 10; b++) {
    cdiv(i + '' + b);
  }
}
```

Comment: but this only max 10 after 10 it will stop.

Comment: I tinker around with the parameters to make it work. Thanks!